# Selenium switch to frame

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Selenium python script written to automate certain tasks on a website, when it comes to run the line of codes below it will stop with an error saying unable to locate such element.

**Code:**

```
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".button-text").click()
```

**Error:**
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".button-text"}`

Although if I run the same exact code above again after Selenium stopping because of the error, it is able to find the element and continue with the script. I believe the issue is related to switching to the frame?

**I have so far tried the following things:**
added `driver.refresh()` before the code.

Tried running the code twice in the script although it results in the same error.

```
try:
    driver.switch_to.frame(0)
    time.sleep(4)
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".button-text").click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Attempt 1, error element not found")


try:
    driver.switch_to.frame(0)
    time.sleep(4)
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".button-text").click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Attempt 2, error element not found")
```

I can't figure out what the issue could be since as stated above running the same code again after Selenium stopping works perfectly.

Comment: can you share the html?

Comment: in question show URL to this HTML. Without HTML this question is only waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the site you should switch_to.parent_frame() to close the frame you're already got the information you needed.

Another thing you should do is get the frame reference (id, selector or another more reliable than just the index. You can find it in the HTML.

The same goes with the selector, inspect the page and copy the selector right clicking it.

And to avoid unnecessary waiting, change time.sleep to wait

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 

for attempt in range(3):
        try:
            driver.switch_to.frame(frame reference)
            wait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".button-text")))
            driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".button-text").click()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
            print(f"Attempt {attempt}, error element not found")
```